# Ember-changeset remove field

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to remove a field from a changeset (or set it to undefined) so that when the changeset is applied the field will be removed (or set to undefined) on the model. How can this be achieved?

Cheers

Comment: Could you give some information why it is not possible to set the value of that field to `undefined`?

Comment: Applying the changeset makes no difference to the model.

Answer (score 1):

[ember-changeset](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-changeset) does not support setting a value to `undefined`. Calling `changeset.set()` with `undefined` as value *does not* set the value.

```
let obj = Ember.Object.create({
  foo: 'a',
  bar: 'b'
});
let changeset = new Changeset(user);
changeset.set('foo', null);
changeset.set('bar', undefined);
changeset.get('bar'); // b
changeset.get('change'); // { foo: null }
```

I'm quite surprised about that myself. Since it's not expected behavior and it does not seem to be documented, I think it should be considered a bug and get fixed.

I've opened a pull request for ember-changeset adding a failing test: https://github.com/DockYard/ember-changeset/pull/191